# jquery dialog refreshes page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Whenever I click on my button to open a jquery ui dialog box, it will briefly display (less than a second) and then the page will refresh.  I had this code working 3 days ago, but when I came back and expanded it to contain a second dialog box this morning, everything broke.  Remove the new code hasn't fixed anything.  Here's the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.astext {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Sprinkler Controller - Main</title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="display:inline-block" id="refreshHolder"></div>

<div id="manualDur" title="0=Forever">
  <form id="manualForm" method="get" action="gpio_functions.php">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="manDur">Duration</label>
      <input type="text" name="manDur" id="manDur"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="action"id="manAction"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="pin"id="manPin"/>  
    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" type="button" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

<div id="autoedits">
  <form method="post" action="auto.php">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="hidden" name="action"id="autoAction"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="pin"id="autoPin"/>
    </fieldset>
  <input type="hidden" type="button" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

<div id="descriptions">
  <form  method="get" action="gpio_functions.php">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="desc">Description: </label>
      <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="pin"id="descPin"/>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" type="button" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#manualDur").dialog({
        autoOpen: false, 
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          },
          "OK": function() {  
            submitForm();
          }
        }
      });      

    $("#Descriptions").dialog({
        autoOpen : false, 
        modal : true,
        buttons: {
          "Cancel": function(){
            $(this).dialog("close");
          },
          "OK": function(){  
            submitDescriptions();
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        }
    });
      refreshTable();
  });
    function refreshTable(){
        $('#refreshHolder').load('refreshTable.php', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
        });
    }
    function toggle($pin) {
      if (document.forms["pin"+$pin+"toggle"]["action"].value == "turnOn") {
        $('#manDur').attr("value", document.forms["pin"+$pin+"toggle"]["manDur"].value);
        $('#manAction').attr("value", document.forms["pin"+$pin+"toggle"]["action"].value);
        $('#manPin').attr("value", $pin);
        $('#manualDur').dialog("open");
      } else if (document.forms["pin"+$pin+"toggle"]["action"].value == "turnOff") {
        $('#manDur').attr("value", "0");
        $('#manAction').attr("value", document.forms["pin"+$pin+"toggle"]["action"].value);
        $('#manPin').attr("value", $pin);
        submitForm();
      } else if (document.forms["pin"+$pin+"toggle"]["action"].value == "autoEdits") {
        $('#autoAction').attr("value", document.forms["pin"+$pin+"toggle"]["action"].value);
        $('#autoPin').attr("value", $pin);
        $('#autoedits').submit();
      }
    } 
    function submitForm(){
      $('#manualForm').submit();
      $('#manualDur').dialog("close");
    }

    function submitDescriptions(){
      $('#Descriptions').submit();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've added some break points and can confirm that up until I call

`$('#manualDur').dialog("open");`

to actually open the dialog everything is being passed correctly.  When the dialog opens I see the title is correct and the text inside it is correct, but then it closes.  It is not submitting the form (I've tested and confirmed this to be true).

Additionally if I change the open command to something like

```
$('#manualDur').dialog("{
  beforeClose: function( event, ui ) {go-to-webpage}");
});
```

or

```
$('#manualDur').dialog("{
  Close: function( event, ui ) {go-to-webpage}");
});
```

then nothing happens.  It's as if everything is crashing and the page just reloads.  Any idea what's causing this?

Edit: One important note, I call this function by clicking on an image:

```
echo '<td><form name="pin' . $pinNumber . 'toggle" action="main.php" onclick="toggle('.$pinNumber.')"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="' . $action . '"><input type="hidden" name="manDur" value="' . $manDur . '"><input type="image" src="'.$image.'"width="70"></form></td>';
```

Comment: one note: you should change $("#Descriptions") selector to $("#descriptions")

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I had stopped testing out that part of my code until I had worked out why the dialog was closing immediately and reloading the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a problem related to placing the function call on clicking on an image.  I needed to add "return false" to the function call to get it to work so it changed from

```
echo '<td><form name="pin' . $pinNumber . 'toggle" action="main.php" onclick="toggle('.$pinNumber.')"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="' . $action . '"><input type="hidden" name="manDur" value="' . $manDur . '"><input type="image" src="'.$image.'"width="70"></form></td>';
```

to

```
echo '<td><form name="pin' . $pinNumber . 'toggle" action="main.php" onclick="toggle('.$pinNumber.'); return false"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="' . $action . '"><input type="hidden" name="manDur" value="' . $manDur . '"><input type="image" src="'.$image.'"width="70"></form></td>';
```

Comment: I didn't want to muddy the answer with this, but while I know that return false fixes the problem, I do not understand *why* it fixes the problem.  I had seen people suggesting using return false in other contexts (such as within the dialog function or the dialog declaration), but it was a complete fluke I found information about needing to include it when using an image as a button.  I did not have to include "return false" when I just used a regular button.